# remove sequences of duplicates longer than a specified length in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

say I have a pandas series which contains some sequences of duplicates, e.g. like this:

```py
pd.Series([
1,2,3,0,0,4,5,6,0,0,0,0,7,1,1,1,8,9,0,10
])
```

My goal is to find an easy method for removing / replacing with nan all duplicate sequences that are longer than a chosen length L. For instance if L=3, the series would look like this:

```py
pd.Series([
1,2,3,0,0,4,5,6,nan,nan,nan,nan,7,nan,nan,nan,8,9,0,10
])
```

(or with the nan's removed).

Also, altering the code to keep always the first element of the duplicates would be interesting:

```py
pd.Series([
1,2,3,0,0,4,5,6,0,nan,nan,nan,7,1,nan,nan,8,9,0,10
])
```

Next challenge would be to have this code work efficiently for a DataFrame along axis=0.

Thanks!

Best, JZ

Comment: `Next challenge would be to have this code work efficiently for a DataFrame along axis=0.` - it means in many columns?

Comment: yes for each column individually replace with nans and keep the first value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create consecutive groups by compared shifted values by cumualtive sum to helper `g` Series and then count values by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and compare by [`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) for greater or equal, add missing values by mask by [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
g = s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()
s = s.mask(g.map(g.value_counts()).ge(3))
print (s)

0      1.0
1      2.0
2      3.0
3      0.0
4      0.0
5      4.0
6      5.0
7      6.0
8      NaN
9      NaN
10     NaN
11     NaN
12     7.0
13     NaN
14     NaN
15     NaN
16     8.0
17     9.0
18     0.0
19    10.0
dtype: float64
```

Alternative solution with first duplicates is chain [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) by `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
s = s.mask(g.map(g.value_counts()).ge(3) & g.duplicated())
print (s)
0      1.0
1      2.0
2      3.0
3      0.0
4      0.0
5      4.0
6      5.0
7      6.0
8      0.0
9      NaN
10     NaN
11     NaN
12     7.0
13     1.0
14     NaN
15     NaN
16     8.0
17     9.0
18     0.0
19    10.0
dtype: float64
```

Solution for multiple columns is changed:

```
cols = ['a','b','c']
f = lambda x: x.map(x.value_counts())
df1 = df.mask(df[cols].ne(df[cols].shift()).cumsum().apply(f).ge(3))
print (df1)
       a     b     c
0    1.0   1.0   1.0
1    2.0   2.0   2.0
2    3.0   3.0   3.0
3    0.0   0.0   0.0
4    0.0   0.0   0.0
5    4.0   4.0   4.0
6    5.0   5.0   5.0
7    6.0   6.0   6.0
8    NaN   NaN   NaN
9    NaN   NaN   NaN
10   NaN   NaN   NaN
11   NaN   NaN   NaN
12   7.0   7.0   7.0
13   NaN   NaN   NaN
14   NaN   NaN   NaN
15   NaN   NaN   NaN
16   8.0   8.0   8.0
17   9.0   9.0   9.0
18   0.0   0.0   0.0
19  10.0  10.0  10.0
```

For second solution:

```
cols = ['a','b','c']
f = lambda x: x.map(x.value_counts()).ge(3) & x.duplicated()
df1 = df.mask(df[cols].ne(df[cols].shift()).cumsum().apply(f))
```

Comment: thanks, you're a boss! exactly what i needed! where did you learn this compact coding? XD

Comment: done, thanks again. can you refer me some nice coding sources or advice? anything python related that you would recommend for improving coding style.